# Change the style of matSelect when the options are open

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to change properties of mat-select when options are open?

```
<mat-select class="selector">
     <mat-option><mat-option>
</mat-select>

.selector:focus {
   color: green;
}
```

I tried with focus but it doesn't work very well, it is possible to click on mat select and not open the options.

Solution: Solved the issue using

```
.mat-select[aria-expanded="true"] { 
    color: green 
}
```

Comment: I solved the issue using .mat-select[aria-expanded="true"]  {
    color: green
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using .mat-select[aria-expanded="true"] { color: green }